# How can I stop typing effect after second line?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, javascript-objects

I want to stop typing when it writes the second line. Just Display the Second line, should not execute again, and when it stops right border should be **none**.
Anybody, please help me I need to fix it now.

```js
var _CONTENT = [ "First line.", "Second Line." ];
var _PART = 0;
var _PART_INDEX = 0;
var _INTERVAL_VAL;
var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");
function Type() { 
    var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
    _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
    _PART_INDEX++;
    if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        setTimeout(function() {
            _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
        }, 1000);

    }
}
function Delete() {
    var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
    _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
    _PART_INDEX--;
    if(text === '') {
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
            _PART = 0;
        else
            _PART++;
        _PART_INDEX = 0;
        setTimeout(function() {
            _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
        }, 200);
clearInterval(_CONTENT);

    }
}
_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```css
#text {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 50px;
    border-right: 6px solid #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Mermaid;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-content">
    <h1><div id="text"></div></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var _CONTENT = [ "First line.", "Second Line." ];
var _PART = 0;
var _PART_INDEX = 0;
var _INTERVAL_VAL;
var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");
function Type() { 
    var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
  
   
    _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
    _PART_INDEX++;
     if(text==="Second Line."){

      clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    }
    else if(text === _CONTENT[_PART] ) {
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        setTimeout(function() {
            _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
        }, 1000);

    }
}
function Delete() {
    var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
    _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
    _PART_INDEX--;
    if(text === '') {
        clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
        if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
            _PART = 0;
        else
            _PART++;
        _PART_INDEX = 0;
        setTimeout(function() {
            _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
        }, 200);
clearInterval(_CONTENT);

    }
}
_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```html
<div id="hello-content">
    <h1><div id="text"></div></h1>
</div>
```